# LocalBusiness & Organization schema together in JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have a local business, I have a blog, and I have services. I'm a digital marketer, you can see my schema here: [https://www.sitecentre.com.au](https://www.sitecentre.com.au/) (view the source code). Most of it's on the home page, but some is on blog articles are /blog and click an article.

I feel as if I'm doing it wrong.

Schema is really confusing, so Google has announced, don't include `Organization` schema on every page, it's only needed on one. So, I set the `"@id": "https://www.example.com/#Organisation"` and I add that schema to the home page only, now where do I put my `LocalBusiness`? I can set it to `"@id": "https://www.example.com/#LocalBusiness"`.

Then I add `WebSite` and `WebPage` to the home page as well.

Now let's say one of my service pages like Hosting.

I don't need `LocalBusiness` or `Organization` on this page? Because it's on the home page? Am I right here? So on the Service page I could have `Service` schema, `Review`, `WebPage` but not `WebSite`, and `BreadcrumbList`?

The issue is if I then do something like `publisher` and call the organisation `url` it fails in the Google Schema Tester because `Organization` isn't found on that page.

Same goes for the blog. Obviously, on a blog I need to have a publisher like: `"publisher": { "@id": "https://www.example.com/#Organisation" }`.

This will fail because `Organization` schema is on the home page. Not the current page.

It gets technical because on the home page Google recognizes only `LocalBusiness` not `Organization` because both are on there.

It's hard to workout what to do.

Now if I do something like put all my `Organization` or `LocalBusiness` schema on the home page then on blog I put both but with limited data and have the `@id` pointing to the home page I can pass validation but does this not overwrite the home page or because the `@id` matches the home page it uses the home page?

Does anyone have an answer? Please don't link me to the definition or some generator. I've read it all. Trust me, I've read IT ALL. The confusion isn't how to write Schema.org or why. It's answering a question based on experience because the answer isn't actually out there.

Comment: PS: If someone can prove then genuinely know their stuff on this and can get my schema perfect. I'll genuinely pay. This is real important to me.

Comment: You can see it fails here: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitecentre.com.au%2Fseo%2Flocal although the id is correct...

Comment: 1) "Google has announced": Can you give a link to this announcement? 2) Do you want to get a specific rich result in Google Search? If yes, which one?

Comment: @unor https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-do-not-put-organization-schema-markup-on-every-page/289981/ I believe it was in an interview so this is the most authority cite of the announcement. and here is someone who actually got a pen for havign it on every page: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82507/should-schema-org-organization-data-about-my-company-be-on-every-page

Comment: Although with sub 20 pages I'm not even close to getting a pen for it, it's still not correct obviously. I'm just looking for what is the correct way to run a LocalBusiness schema because Organisation is out ranked by LocalBusiness yet, you need Organisation for things like publisher on blogs and articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalBusiness is a sub-type of Organization. What this means is you can switch your Organization entity to be a LocalBusiness entity and it will still function as an Organization, with the extra bits that LocalBusiness add.

So you can add a detailed LocalBusiness on the home page that includes all the Organization info and the LocalBusiness info. And give it an id like you suggested:

```
https://www.example.com/#LocalBusiness
```

This is how you can reference it from other pages. When you need to reference your business, include a very basic version of the LocalBusiness that includes the type, name, its id and the url. That's enough info needed on those other pages, while also indicating there is more info available about the business under that id and url. e.g.

```
"publisher": {
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "@id": "https://www.example.com/#LocalBusiness",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "name": "Example Ltd"
}
```

Comment: You're the best! I've ran this and validated it. I still have the issue where this is only meant for the home page. So on a blog schema I reference the local business ID being the home page url and #LocalBusiness but it still comes up invalid because the localbusiness schema is not on the blog page itself. Am I meant to add a shortened version of the local business for this?

Comment: Yes, add the shortened version so it validates. And as all copies use the same id they will be considered as referencing the same entity.